# Error when using Mingw on Windows

Tags: linux, windows, eclipse, cross-compiling, mingw32

I am completely new to this. I have a C program which compiles fine and runs fine on linux. I want to run the same code on a Windows machine so I am using the cross compiler Mingw. However every time i try and build the project i get this error:

```
14:51:21 **** Incremental Build of configuration Default for project zbar-0.10 ****
make all
make  all-am
make[1]: Entering directory `D:/zbar-0.10'
 ! was unexpected at this time.
make[1]: *** [include/config.h] Error 255
make[1]: Leaving directory `D:/zbar-0.10'
make: *** [all] Error 2

14:51:26 Build Finished (took 4s.493ms)
```

I have googled around and still do not understand why i am getting it. Any advice?

Comment: Shoot, and I've even built zbar on windows....

Comment: @Jim how do i get it to build on windows

Comment: If you are just needing the 32-bit, why not grab the dll?  It's out there.

Comment: am making modifications to it so I need the source

Comment: I'm trying to remember. I didn't use eclipse, just shell calls.  Did you do all the configure stuff?  There's stuff online on how to build it in 32-bit.  64-bit was a bitch, especially to make the .dll.

Comment: ive looked around online the instructions for the 32-bit dont seem to be working for me

Comment: http://sourceforge.net/apps/mediawiki/zbar/index.php?title=HOWTO:_Compile_with_MinGW_in_Windows

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/34454/discussion-between-jim-and-cxzp)

Answer (score 0):

Build with exact versions of tools as specified in:  http://sourceforge.net/apps/mediawiki/zbar/index.php?title=HOWTO:_Compile_with_MinGW_in_Windows

The code is old and the make will break with newer versions.

Comment: im having some problems with the libiconv step ... you around ?

Comment: What;s up?  You have to find the right lbiconv, the 32-bit one.

Comment: have posted in the chat, got the downloads done, having trouble with the make install, unknown type uint32_t I'm assuming the reason something hasn't been installed correctly on the mingw side? what's your opinion and did you have similar issues?